# How to make related mutations in GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, api, express

How can we implement associated mutations in GraphQL?

I decided to make a portfolio for myself to study GraphQL and also to learn a new tool. I didn't have any difficulties until the moment when I needed to add an entry to my portfolio and images attached to it.

When you add an entry to a portfolio, it has related entities that are represented as additional images. They have a title, description, and multiple tags. The images, like the portfolio record itself, are in different tables and are linked by the ID of the portfolio record.

Here is where the question arises: how to add an entry with additional images in one mutation and link them, and how to do it correctly?

I searched the forums and clear manual I have not found. I have a couple of ideas on how to do this: use subscriptions or perform mutations through Promise. I suppose the first method is correct, but there are still doubts. Prompt how correctly to work with such mutations. Thank you for listening.

In development I use GraphQL, Apollo, Vue and Laravel.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portfolio_works` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `portfolio_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portfolio_work_images` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `portfolio_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `portfolio_work_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overthinking things. Here is an approach:

```
type Portfolio {
    id: ID!
    portfolioImages: [PortfolioImages]
    title: String
    image: String
    description: String
}

type PortfolioImages {
    id: ID!
    portfolio: Portfolio
    image: String
    title: String
}

input PortfolioInput {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    image: String!
    description: String
}

input PortfolioImagesInput {
    image: String
    title: String
}

extend type RootMutation {
    # Creates a new portfolio
    createPortfolio(item: PortfolioInput!, images: PortfolioImagesInput): Portfolio
}
```

Then inside your function that maps to the createPortfolio mutation you would create a MySQL transaction to create the necessary rows of data for your relationship and then `COMMIT` the [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html). Example of doing a transaction: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#transactions